# SQL Server - More efficient way of joining three tables without parent table

Tags: sql-server

This is an issue I have been working on for a while, I have three tables, all of which share 3 of the same columns but there are rows that are unique to each row. I would like to combine all of the tables without duplicating rows. I have a working solution but I feel like it might not be the most efficient. I tried using joins but found that without a parent table, I wasn't getting the expected number of results. My solution which does yield the correct number of results(I've cut some columns for simplicity):

```
--Create table
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
   ID, 
   Date
)

-- Insert rows that are only in db1
INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT 
   ID, 
   Date
FROM test.dbo.db1
-- Do not include rows shared by db1 and db2
EXCEPT
(
   SELECT 
      ID, 
      Date
   FROM test.dbo.db2

   INTERSECT 

   SELECT 
      ID,
      Date
   FROM test.dbo.db1
)
EXCEPT
-- And not in db1 and db3
(
    SELECT
       ID, 
       Date
    FROM test.dbo.db1

    INTERSECT

    SELECT
      ID,
      Date
    FROM test.dbo.db3

)
EXCEPT 
-- And not in db1, db2 and db3
 ** Code where I intersect all 3 tables
```

I repeat the above steps for all three tables and then add the intersections for each combined ID/Date(db1+d2+db3, db1+db2, etc...)

Does anyone know of a way to do this that is more direct and to the point? I have tried doing a full join of all of them but without a parent table with all of the ID's, I found the ID's that only appear in the other two tables don't show up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT
       ID, 
       Date
FROM test.dbo.db1

UNION

SELECT
       ID, 
       Date
FROM test.dbo.db2

UNION

SELECT
       ID, 
       Date
FROM test.dbo.db3
```

The `UNION` takes care of removing duplicates.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but I am missing close to 300,000 records when I use this method.

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected output in your question and I will update my answer.

Comment: I am so sorry, I checked my solution and it looks like I was double counting those 300,000 in my working solution so once I removed those I realized that your solution worked perfectly.